# Wrapping <mat-card> within a container - angular/material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Is it possible to:

1. Display  components of defined width in a row rather than the default column
2. Wrap the cards within another defined container

I have tried to do this without success so far....

material buttons DO wrap in this way, I am just wanting to replicate the experience with cards...

Please see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/wrapping-cards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in angular material 1, layout API, flexbox css & media query are available, like `layout="row | column"` directives.

but in angular they make it a separate module named [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), so you can leverage it in your code.
[**live working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/wrapping-cards-spacig)

here is live examples of [flex-layout](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

Comment: Your demo is exactly what I had found myself, setting `display: flex; flex-direction: row`, but I am wanting the cards to wrap around the inside of the container, not simply go atop it and off of the page in one row...

Comment: Genius @Praveen! I will put this into my work asap! <3

Comment: I couldn't get it to work within my app for some reason :-( Maybe there was other CSS interfering with it? It worked perfectly when I extracted my components into a StackBlitz app, but not when compiling with my IDE for some reason. I have since found an alternative by using `.container {display: flex; flex-flow: wrap}`

Answer (score 1):

Use fxLayout="row wrap" now as fxLayoutWrap was deprecated.